# CSS Column Height Scrolling

Tags: html, css, overflow, multiple-columns

I'm having an issue with creating overflows inside of a relatively-sized vertical div.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZgL59/

Basically, I have one large vertical column, with two percentage-based divs inside of it. The bottom div has content in there that is larger than the div, with overflow-y:scroll on it.

However, as you can see in the fiddle the bottom amount of content gets cut off depending on the browser (the last 'Y' in the fiddle is not entirely visible). This is browser dependent. Is there a fix for this? I don't want to fall down the rabbit hole of trying to please every browser with a different height.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="inner1">X</div>
     <div class="inner2">
         Tons of Content...
     </div>
 </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
 html, body {
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
 }

 .container {
    height:100%;
    background:blue;
 }

 .inner1 {
    height:30%;
    background:red;
 }

 .inner2 {
    height:70%;
    background:green;
    overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right in thinking what you mean by 'cut off', see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVrL6/), setting the `margin`and `padding` to `0px` on the body should fix it. Tested in Chrome, FF and IE10 and looks OK (again, if I understand the question).

Comment: What is that difference after you added padding and margin into null..? am seeing same odd screen..? o.O

Comment: The scrollbar is kept within the confines of the body. Can you provide more information on the perceived and expected behaviour? I cant see the content being cut off as you note :(

Comment: In the first fiddle, the bottom 'Y' was cut off, but in yours, it wasn't! This is very promising, I'm going to hack on my more complicated solution and see if it leads to a full fix. Basically the scrollbar goes past the bottom of the browser sometimes, and it's driving me crazy!

Comment: Its typically due to the fact the body element by default has margin/padding values. Incidentally if you own code is more complex, padding/margin values on parent/nested containers can also cause unforseen issues if not handled correctly

Comment: Thanks, i think this is the right direction -- will keep this post up to date with my developments!